# Parallax scrolling - scroll over absolute element

Tags: jquery, css

I have an absolutely position "hero" section on my page. When scrolling down the page I'd like to have the content below scroll over the top of the hero section.

To do this I update the `top` position of the lower content as you scroll down the page. However, doing so appears to push the hero unit off the page rather than simply scrolling over the top of it.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="hero">
        <div class="hero-content">
             <h1>loud noises.</h1>
             <p class="strapline">we make loud noises so you don't have to</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="inner">
        <section class="feature-1">
             <h2>Some awesome feature</h2>
        </section>
        <section class="feature-2">
             <h2>Some awesome feature</h2>
        </section>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #3498db;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    /*max-height: 768px; set the height limit here */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.inner').css('top', $('.hero').height() - $(window).scrollTop());
});
```

Demo:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/benfosterdev/LycXL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have given absolute value to `.hero`, Instead of that try using `fixed`

**CSS**

```
.hero {
    position: fixed;
}
```

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LycXL/4/)**

Comment: This worked and it means I don't actually need the javascript to set the `.inner` top position.

Answer (score -1):

The background then should be fixed.

Add

> background-attachment:fixed;

to your .hero:after class.